# Subtraction operation doesn't work

Tags: c, windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char letter;
    float n1, n2, sum;
    printf("What operation do you want to use \n\nA)Addidtion\nB)Subtraction\nC)Multiplacation\nD)Division\n");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%f", &n1);
    printf("Please enter a second number: ");
    scanf("%f", &n2);
if(letter == 'A' ||'a'){
        sum = n1 + n2;
    printf("The sum of %.2f plus %.2f is %.2f", n1, n2, sum);
}else if(letter == 'b' || 'B'){
    sum = n1 - n2;
    printf("The sum of %.2f minus %.2f is %.2f", n1, n2, sum);
}
return 0;
}
```

The substraction doesnt work could you help me fix this? i couldn't, when i run the program i type b and then type 12 and then 2 and it gives me 14? it is supposed to be 10

Comment: Double-check your second OR conditions, they evaluate to TRUE.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you reported the input and output of your program

Comment: Also, just a hint, since it looks like you are starting out: always try to make your variable names as clear as possible. In your case, `sum` could be changed to `result`, since you hold the result for both adittion **or** subtraction operations in it :-)

Answer (score 8):

```
if(letter == 'A' ||'a')
```

is not doing what you want.

```
if(letter == 'A' || letter == 'a')
```

is what you want.

The `||` operation evaluates its operands as truth values and evaluates to `1` if one of them evaluates to `true`. No matter if `letter == 'A'` is true, at least the `'a'` - which is `!= 0` - "brings the truth".

Comment: @user3096416 and also make sure to replicate this change to your second `if` statement

Comment: Because 'a' in the C language will actually evaluate to true, so your first if is really "letter == 'A' || true", so the code will always do addition.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(letter == 'A' ||'a')
```

is equivalent to

```
if(letter == 'A' || 97) // 'a' == 97
```

in a if statement, a number !=0 is evaluated to true.

Hence, your condition is equivalent to

```
if(true) {
  sum = n1 + n2;
  printf("The sum of %.2f plus %.2f is %.2f", n1, n2, sum);
} else {
  //Not reachable statement. The compiler should warn you.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the wrong `if` statement, I would expect the output of your program to be **anyway** somehow "correct" in the phrase it printed in all cases. Maybe it will compute sum when asked for subtraction, but the printed phrase, I repeat, should be formally correct.